# Assign 'Manage Announcements' Permission for Guest Community to a Role - Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet, portal, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay 6.0.6 Portal.
How do I assign 'Manage Announcements' Permission for Guest Community to a particular Role?
All the users in that role should be able to add Announcements which are visible in the portlet placed in the public pages of Guest Community.

I need my community to be visible in the Distribution Scope. How do I do that?
[image: Announcement Portlet in the Guest/Open Community]

I was able to assign the Manage Announcements to other roles, but I couldn't do it on an open community level. I tried defining permissions for the role to which I need to assign permissions and tried adding Community and Announcements Resource level limited to the scope of my community without any effect. I don't see my Open (Guest) community in the Distribution scope. Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Defining Permissions for the Target Role]

Comment: Can anyone direct me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´m using Liferay 6.1 but I think this may help. Logged as admin, go to Control Panel and on the left hand side, below Portal, in "Roles", you see all the Roles. In "actions" from the role you want to grant these permissions, select "define permissions".

Inside that, select from Portal Roles section, the option "Manage Announcements", and click "Save". The users with this role will be able to create new entries, and modify entries that they create.

Hope it helps,

Dámaris.

Comment: Damaris, thanks for the instructions. I did that for assigning Role-permissions. But I am looking for a community level distribution scope as you can see in the first screenshot. Do you know of any way we can fill that section?